# Drawables not Found Under Custom Build Type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-drawable, android-build-type

I have tried to configure a build type for my application that is identical with my release configuration except that it loads some sample data for testing the app. I performed the following steps:

I use the following `buildTypes` configuration in the app's `build.gradle`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        versionNameSuffix "-debug"
    }
    sampledata {
        applicationIdSuffix ".sampledata"
        versionNameSuffix "-sampledata"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main { res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/androidTest/res'] }
    sampledata { res.srcDirs = ['src/sampledata/res', 'src/main/res'] }
}
```

I created the corresponding source set (folder structure) under the `src` folder.

When I try to get a resource using the following statement the resource is not found (returning 0):

```
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("someResource", "drawable", "com.myapp");
```

I had no trouble using the string resources in my source set but **I'm not able to access the drawables** in this configuration. Moving them to the `drawable` folder under `main` did not work either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the resources in the source set the package name must match that of the build type, i.e. include the `applicationIdSuffix`. Change the `getIdentifier()` statement to

```
int resId = context.getResources()
    .getIdentifier("someResource", "drawable", "com.myapp.sampledata");
```

or

```
int resId = context.getResources()
    .getIdentifier("someResource", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
```